# Installing ZF2 IIS7

Tags: iis-7, zend-framework2

I have been trying to install ZF2 on IIS7, the issue I am having is that I need to add

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => '/accounting/public/'
),
```

in the global in order for the headers css, js to work, this updates the

```
->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/jquery-ui.css')
```

and I get the full path "/accounting/public/css/jquery-ui.css"

but the real problem comes on the input images I have on the views like this one:

```
<input type='image' name='pay' value=1> src='/img/payment-32.png' title='Pay'>
```

one solution can be

```
<input type='image' name='pay' value=1> src= $this->basePath().'/img/payment-32.png' title='Pay'>
```

If I open the firebug and go to the head tag and position myself over the a link with the cursors i can see `"http://localhost/js/jquery.js"` but even tough is there is as if the root path it still pointing to /public/.

In Apache I dont have that, cud just easily have "/img/payment-32.png" and it will find the image, but for some reason I cant on II7. I know that maybe is a configuration issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

.htacess files do not work with iis you'll have to install a mod rewrite module for iis and configure it to your needs.

There is a blog post covering these steps. Might be worth checking it outhttp://lab.empirio.no/zf2-urlrewriting-in-iis7.html

As the blogpost suggest create a web.config file within the public folder and add a config similar to this:

> Source: http://lab.empirio.no/zf2-urlrewriting-in-iis7.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
            <rules>
               <rule name="Empirio (www.empirio.no)" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                   <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
               </rule>
            </rules>
         </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Yes thats the way I have it, I use that configuration, the server is pointing correctly to the public and the fw is working fine, the only thing that is not getting are the files inside public like img, js etc,,

Comment: how did you set up the home directory within the iis manager?

Comment: Sorry I have been away, I stay with the base_path configuration I need it to deliver the product. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I noticed you are using $this->basePath().'some/path/'. Is there a reason as to why? You can just use $this->basePath('some/path/'); which handles some of the routing issues.

Comment: Thats a good question I found the solution and it worked I am going to try what you are suggesting.